# Type mismatch when using + operator

Tags: scala, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm currently trying to learn how to use Scala but I'm stuck with some syntax problems.

When I type in the scala prompt:

```
import scala.collection.immutable._
var q = Queue[Int](1)
println((q+1).toString)
```

I get the following error:

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
              println((q+1).toString)
```

I just wanted to use the overloaded + operator of the queue defined as below:

> def +[B >: A](elem : B) : Queue[B]
>   Creates a new queue with element added at the end of the old queue.
>   Parameters
>   elem - the element to insert

But it seems that scala does a string concatenation. So, can you help me to understand how to add an element to the queue (without using enqueue which works perfectly; I would like to use the + operator)? And maybe, could you give me some explaination about that behaviour that seems a bit strange for a beginner?

Thank you

Comment: Where did you get that definition from? It is at odds with the current docs

Comment: That method is from some old version of Scala. It was removed in 2.9. Use more recent documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. Google was giving http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.5.0/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.html as a second result for "scala queue immutable". I wasn't so careful and I did not notice that it was for version 2.5. I overestimated the power of google search engine :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator (see [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/#scala.collection.immutable.Queue)):

```
scala> var q = Queue[Int](1)
q: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1)

scala> q :+ 2
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2)

scala> 0 +: q
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(0, 1)
```

Since the `+` operator has no other meaning given those types, Scala defaults to String concatenation, giving you the type mismatch error.